# Why do the author need to add remember for a variable from viewModel?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from the official [sample](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/AdvancedStateAndSideEffectsCodelab).

In my mind, I needn't to wrap a variable from viewModel because it has more long life cycle.

But why do the author need to add remember for a variable from viewModel ?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun DetailsScreen(
    onErrorLoading: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: DetailsViewModel = viewModel()
) {   
     val cityDetails = remember(viewModel) { viewModel.cityDetails }
     ...
}


@HiltViewModel
class DetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val destinationsRepository: DestinationsRepository,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
    ...
    val cityDetails: Result<ExploreModel>
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use remember. You only use it if you want to update your cityDetails inside your viewmodel and you want that update to automatically trigger a recomposiition. Without remember, a recomposition would not occur.

Comment: As @Johann said, it's about recomposition. Compose needs a `State`. We don't use `remember` when exposing a state from the VM if you're using such object (usually with `mutableStateOf`) that compose can interpret.